# Native Method Error in KeyAgreement.generateSecret()

Tags: java, cryptography, ecdh

I'm trying to generate a shared secret with javax.crypto.KeyAgreement:

```
public static byte[] generateSharedSecret(KeyPair localKeyPair, PublicKey clientPublicKey) {
    byte[] sharedSecret = {};
    try {
        KeyAgreement keyAgreement = KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH");
        keyAgreement.init(localKeyPair.getPrivate());
        keyAgreement.doPhase(clientPublicKey, true);

        sharedSecret = keyAgreement.generateSecret();
        MessageDigest hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return sharedSecret;
}
```

but after running the program I give this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException
at sun.security.ec.ECDHKeyAgreement.deriveKey(Native Method)
at sun.security.ec.ECDHKeyAgreement.engineGenerateSecret(ECDHKeyAgreement.java:130)
at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.generateSecret(KeyAgreement.java:586)
at io.softitecture.jpushup.keygen.ECDHKeyGenerator.generateSharedSecret(ECDHKeyGenerator.java:47)
at io.softitecture.jpushup.payload.PayloadEncryptor.encrypt(PayloadEncryptor.java:19)
at io.softitecture.App.main(App.java:15)
```

would you please help me out with this and tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure this is the code that is failing?

Comment: Yes, Actually I think the problem is with my client public key.Thanks! @PresidentJamesK.Polk

Comment: @DanaAmiri Maybe the client public key is in the wrong format or something.